# "E1101" - Instance of "Class" has no "method" member

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylint

I have classes organized like so:

```
class One:
    def funcOne(self):
        doSomething()

class Two(One):
    def funcTwo(self):
        self.funcOne()
```

When I ran this, it worked, and Python's inheritance model allowed for `Two` to be able to call `funcOne`.

However, running Pylint gives me the error:

> [E1101 (no-member), myscript] Instance of 'Two' has no 'funcOne' member

I already looked at [another question on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245414/pylint-warnings-on-inherited-nested-class-members), but that question concerned variables, and the only solution proposed was to put them in a dictionary, which you can't do with methods.

How can I get Pylint to recognize the inheritance behavior?

I'm running Pylint 1.1.0, which is ridiculously old. Maybe that's the cause?

Comment: Try calling `funcOne` inside `funcTwo` with `self`, so: `self.funcOne()`

Comment: @Nicarus sorry, that was a typo in the question, I'll update

Comment: Doesn't "solve" the problem, but you can explicitly ignore this error by adding this line: `# pylint: disable=E1101`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `self.funcOne()`

Also, class One should inherit from object:

```
class One(object):
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I actually do call with `self`. Also, I thought that Python classes implicitly inherit from `object`?

Comment: @Jeeter - only for python 3+. But always better to be explicit in any event.

Comment: @Jeeter - how are you calling funcTwo()?

Comment: OK, so for some reason, when I added the subclass of `object` yesterday, it still failed `pylint`, now it's passing :\. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that my version of Pylint was severely out of date. I was running version 1.1.0, and updated to the newest version 1.6.4, and the warnings were gone!

I assume this is a bug in Pylint that was fixed between the versions.